# java.io.IOException: Is a directory Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to insert images from the drawable folder to ImageView on custom listview. But when i set the images on satisfying the condition its giving the following warnings from getView.

```
    12-27 11:56:56.356: DEBUG/skia(341): ---- read threw an exception
    12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341): java.io.IOException: Is a directory
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.read(Native Method)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:165)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:290)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:166)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
12-27 11:56:56.366: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:309)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:800)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:528)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:305)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.setViewImage(SimpleAdapter.java:264)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:192)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:126)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at com.presentation.activity.ShowListActivity$CustomAdapter.getView(ShowListActivity.java:229)
12-27 11:56:56.378: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
12-27 11:56:56.386: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 11:56:56.396: WARN/System.err(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-27 11:56:56.406: WARN/System.err(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-27 11:56:56.406: WARN/System.err(341):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 11:56:56.466: WARN/System.err(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)


    12-27 11:56:56.406: WARN/System.err(341):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-27 11:56:56.466: DEBUG/skia(341): ---- read threw an exception
12-27 11:56:56.466: DEBUG/skia(341): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
12-27 11:56:56.466: INFO/System.out(341): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
```

I am using a custom adapter that extends the SimpleAdapter and putting the text and icons according to condition.

My custome adapter looks something like..

```
serviceAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, serviceList, R.layout.list_row,
                new String[] { "name", "duration","reason", "remark", "img1", "img2", "img3",
                        "img" }, new int[] { R.id.servicename, R.id.duration,R.id.reason, R.id.remark,
                        R.id.statusImg1, R.id.statusImg2, R.id.statusImg3, R.id.isExpandable });
```

I am putting the corresponding values from a HashMap...

```
HashMap<String, Object> rowValue = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

And image using. `rowValue.put("img2", R.drawable.img);`

Its not throwing any errors but slowing down the application a lot. Can any one let me know what the problem might be...

Comment: Well, people told you that youre pointing to a folder, not to a file. thats true. But you also know that android cant manage folders inside the drawable folder, dont you know? That is, all your images should be on the root of the drawable. You cant have drawable/myfolder/myimage.png. At least not yet. This is just a warning to you.

Comment: I have the drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-xhdpi folders in which I have placed the corresponding images. Doing anything wrong here???

Comment: Oh no, this is right, i meant that you cant have folders inside these folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the image name in  image path. The issue may be in image path. I am sure that **it points to any directory not to file.**

Comment: in my case it's /sdcard/media/images/show/XP-Guide.jpg 
and file there also...but dont know why it's giving this error. any idea over this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is: the image file path pointer to **a folder not file**