# Java.IO.IOException Warning when loading Drawable

Tags: android, image, loading, xamarin.android, drawable

Why does the Android system throw this Exception?

```
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230): java.io.IOException: Is a directory
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.read(Native Method)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:165)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:290)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:166)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:573)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:384)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:412)
05-18 12:33:44.169 W/System.err( 8230):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-18 12:33:44.169 D/skia    ( 8230): ---- read threw an exception
```

I am loading the images into memory like this:

```
return BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fullPathToImage);
```

This is not causing failing problems, but it does cause unnecessary delays in the loading.

The image is stored on the `Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath`. The path is the full path including the image filename and extension. The image does load properly, so why does it do this?

I saw this SO: [java.io.IOException: Is a directory Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641863/java-io-ioexception-is-a-directory-android), but this seems to be related to drawable *resources*, which I am not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be curious to see if you still get the error if you wrapped your DecodeFile call in a check to see whether the file system thinks it's a directory:

```
File f = new File(fullPathToImage);
if (!f.IsDirectory)
{
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fullPathToImage);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a directory: " + fullPathToImage);
}
```

One other possibly useful thought. If you're dealing with very large images and you don't need them to be full resolution, you could possibly improve performance by reducing their size:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.InSampleSize = 4; //Cut the image size to 1/4 the original
return BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile, opts);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was actually me making a mistake. In the line before this, I was building the path. Often the filename was correct, but sometimes the logic would use another filename which was empty. Thus the path was then a directory. Thanks for help in showing me my bad ways.